# PCL Installing Errors

Tags: python, macos, setuptools

Recently I was trying to install pcl-python in my Mac. (github: https://github.com/strawlab/python-pcl )I found the notes in setup.py file and I changed some codes to suit my Mac.

```
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
line 570:ext_args['extra_compile_args'].append(["-stdlib=libstdc++"])
line 587:ext_args['extra_link_args'].append(["-stdlib=libc++"])
```

But when I typed `python setup.py install` in my terminal, other errors occurred. Here are the outputs of my Terminal

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 645, in <module>
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext},
  File "/Users/apple/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.4-h8f450c2_22/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/Users/apple/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.4-h8f450c2_22/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/Users/apple/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.4-h8f450c2_22/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Users/apple/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.4-h8f450c2_22/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "/Users/apple/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.4-h8f450c2_22/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/Users/apple/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.4-h8f450c2_22/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Users/apple/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.4-h8f450c2_22/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/old_build_ext.py", line 185, in run
    _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
  File "/Users/apple/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.4-h8f450c2_22/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "/Users/apple/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.4-h8f450c2_22/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/old_build_ext.py", line 193, in build_extensions
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "/Users/apple/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.4-h8f450c2_22/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 533, in build_extension
    depends=ext.depends)
  File "/Users/apple/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.4-h8f450c2_22/lib/python3.5/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 574, in compile
    self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
  File "/Users/apple/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.4-h8f450c2_22/lib/python3.5/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 118, in _compile
    extra_postargs)
  File "/Users/apple/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.4-h8f450c2_22/lib/python3.5/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 909, in spawn
    spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)
  File "/Users/apple/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.4-h8f450c2_22/lib/python3.5/distutils/spawn.py", line 36, in spawn
    _spawn_posix(cmd, search_path, dry_run=dry_run)
  File "/Users/apple/miniconda3/pkgs/python-3.5.4-h8f450c2_22/lib/python3.5/distutils/spawn.py", line 89, in _spawn_posix
    log.info(' '.join(cmd))
TypeError: sequence item 29: expected str instance, list found
```

My version:

```
Cython = 0.25.2
python version == 3.5.4 
Mac Version == macOS Mojave 10.14.1
```

Comment: Can you check the *requirements* again at https://github.com/strawlab/python-pcl ?

Comment: @dhilmathy I checked, my python version is higher. But does that make difference in this issue?